# How many strings are in a A^4 if there is an empty string in the set of strings?

Tags: formal-languages

Ive been struggling to answer this question. The question is we have A = {[a],[b],[c]} and I want to know how many strings are in A^4 ( A to the power of 4). And also if one of the strings in A was empty how many strings would there be in A^4, for example: A= {[a],[b],[]} ?

Now I understand that A^n means A n times. So in this case A^4 means AAAA. But how do we know how many strings there are.

Comment: Do you know how to solve for $A=\{[a],[b],[c]\}$? If so, please mention your solution.

Comment: When you say solve for A do you mean how many strings there are in A. If we are talking about just A then that would be 3 wouldnt it ? they are a.b and c. But I want to know how many wil there be in A^4

Comment: Since the question is how many strings are there in $A^4$ I mean solve that question for $A=\{[a],[b],[c]\}$.

Comment: Well A^4 = A@A@A@A so {a,b,c} @ {a,b,c} @ {a,b,v} @ {a,b,c} now we go on to concatenate these strings so we get {aa,ab,ac,ba,bb,bc,ca,cb,cc}@{a,b,c}@{a,b,c} and then carrying on {aaa,aab,aac.....} and so on but as you can see this takes a lot of time to work out. I wanted to know if there is like a formula we can use to work this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $A=\{[a],[b],[c]\}$ then $A^4$ is the set of strings that have length $4$ and all characters are $a$, $b$ or $c$. This means that for every character there are $3$ options. Since there are $4$ characters, this gives $3^4=81$ options in total.

If we have $A=\{[a],[b],[]\}$ then $A^4$ is the set of all strings that have length *at most* $4$ and all characters are $a$ or $b$. This means that for every character there are $2$ options. We can consider all possible lengths of strings in $A^4$, which are $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$ or $4$. We find that $A^4$ has $1+2+2^2+2^3+2^4=31$ strings in total.

Comment: Thank you for this. I think I understand it. So instead of 3 characters, say we had 4 ie. A = {[a],[b],[c],[d]} then A^4 would be 4^4=256? And again if one of the strings was an empty string A={[a],[b],[c],[]} then A^4 is the set of all strings that have length at most 4 and our characters are a or b or c giving us 3 options. Then the possible lengths of strings in A^4 can be 0,1,2,3 or 4. We can the work out A^4 as 1+2+2^2+2^3+2^4+3+3^2+3^3+3^4 = 151. I feel like I am misunderstanding the length part.

Comment: Not quite, if $A=\{[a],[b],[c],[]\}$ then $A^4$ has $1+3+3^2+3^3+3^4=121$ elements. The point is that any element has length *at most* $4$, so either $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$ or $4$. There are $3^0=1$ of length $0$, $3^1=3$ of length $1$, $3^2$ of length $2$, $3^3$ of length $3$ and $3^4$ of length $4$.

Comment: By the way, a neat formula for solving $1+n+n^2+n^3+...+n^k$ is $\frac{n^{k+1}-1}{n-1}$. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html

Comment: Ok I get it now. Thanks a lot for your help.